# React DOM disappears when I try to use HTTP requests

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, mern

I'm in the process of trying to connect the front end of my MERN application to the back end. The back end works just fine on its own, and I have no problem accessing data by manually executing HTTP requests. Now that I'm trying to connect it to the front end, I seem to be getting stuck everywhere.

My current problem is that when I try to fetch data via HTTP requests, the DOM disappears and displays a blank page.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import ItemRequests from "./dataservices/items.js"

function ItemList(props){
   [items, setItems] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      ItemRequests.getAll()
      .then(results => {
          console.log(results)
          setItems(results.data)
      })
      .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
      })

   }, [])

   return(
      <h6>If this prints the issue has been resolved<h6/>
      {/*Additional code*/}
   )

}
```

ItemRequests class: contains all the requests specific to the Items collection

```
import http from "http-config"

class ItemRequests{
   getAll(page = 0){
      return http.get("?page=" + page)
   }
}

export default ItemRequests
```

http-config file

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create(){
   baseURL: "https://localhost:XXXX/route/to/server",
   headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
}
}
```

All other routes in the front end are functional. Only this route, which executes HTTP requests is not rendering properly. I'm debugging right now to see if I can gain any further details, but I would appreciate any insight from here.

Edit: According to my browser's console:

> Uncaught TypeError: *services_items__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.getAll is not a function

So for some reason JS does not recognize getAll() as a function, even though it is defined.

Comment: What does the console say? I'd start by adding an empty dependency array to `useEffect` to prevent an infinite loop...

Comment: The console is empty Edit: NEvermind, the console is NOT empty, the errors were just hidden behind a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemsRequests` is a class. You cannot invoke a non-static function directly from a class. So, in order for this code to work, you need to do one of two things:

1. Instantiate an object of type `ItemsRequest` inside `useEffect()`

```
ItemsRequests request = new ItemsRequests()

request.getAll()
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results)
    setItems(results.data)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e) 
  })
```

OR 2. Make your `getAll()` method in `ItemsRequests` a static method

```
class ItemRequests{
   static getAll(page = 0){
      return http.get("?page=" + page)
   }
}
```

For this program's purposes, it makes more sense to go with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Your "ItemList" method seems totally broken to me, like you copy/pasted stuff and got it mixed badly.

I didn't try this, but maybe this is the right way:

```
function ItemList(props) {
[items, setItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        ItemRequests.getAll()
            .then(results => {
                    console.log(results)
                    setItems(results.data))
            }
    ).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
}, [])
```

}

Maybe you give it a shot?

Comment: The problem was that my `getAll()` function was not defined as a static function, and thus could not be called unless I created a new `ItemRequests` object. My DOM renders now. I have a different problem now though.

Comment: Ok, glad that you solved it. Keep on fighting. ;)